# How can i bulk remove page breaks <!--nextpage--> in wordpress posts?

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I'm trying to remove pagebreaks (`<!--nextpage-->`) within my posts' contents. I have so many posts with pagebreaks that need to be removed, that I'd like to bulk-remove that code, or disable that function if possible. How can I achieve this? Thank you for help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1iBs.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb75y.png

Comment: By the way i'm using latest version of wordpress

Comment: Maybe https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183582/how-to-ignore-or-disable-nextpage-tag resolves your issue?

Comment: Thank you i tried but it couldn't work. I solved my problem delete (<!--nextpage-->) tags in posts from database.

Comment: You should post what you did as an answer (presuming it worked, I thought DB values in WP were serialized)